# char array/string is empty when sent to function

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a function that at the moment doesn't do anything because the char array I send as parameter has no value. I can write out the data before the function and get the expected output but if I write out in the function nothing come out even if It's the first thing I do.

I first write out the string and then convert it to a char array. I have also tried with just a normal string as parameter with the same result.

```
std::cout << block;
block = this->removeNullCharacters(block.c_str());
```

Output of the first cout is : "0/"

The output of the function below is nothing. Nothing at all is shown up in the console.

```
std::string FileSystem::removeNullCharacters(const char * input){
    std::string out = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 512; ++i){
        std::cout << i << ": " << input[i];

        /*if(input[i] == '\0'){
            return out;
        }
        else{
            out += input[i];
        }*/
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Try to use DDD to watch the input value... anyway I guess that the method block.c_str() is returning nothing

Comment: @101010  It's not the returned value I have problem with. std::cout in the function. There is nothing in the input[i].

Comment: @Izuel You was right on that the block.c_str() returns nothing so I changed to string as input and now I get that some places in the string i filled and wierd. If i try to write out the whole string the I see nothing.

Comment: does `block` contain a single null character ?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear at all what you try to achieve or, in other words, you question is not complete.

`input` is a pointer to `char` and points to the first element of an `array` of `char`s of size 512.

`out` is an empty string and returned at the end of the function.

`block` is schizophren, a pointer to `char` and a `std::string` at the same time i guess. You need to fix this one really.

Try this. I think you want to pass a pointer to a sequence of `char`s to the function and concatenate each `char` to the `string` until the end of the sequence (which is terminated by `\0`). Forget about the size completely and simply use the null termination as a loop condition.

```
std::string FileSystem::removeNullCharacters(const char * input){
    std::string out = "";
    for(int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        std::cout << i << ": " << input[i];
        out += input[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

But you gotta make sure you pass in an array of `char`s or a valid pointer to `char` (which is the beginning of a sequence of `char`s and the last element is `\0`).